# Does ubuntu work on an Acer TravelMate 5742Z?

Tags: installation, drivers, acer

I have an Acer TravelMate 5742Z, and I would like to install Ubuntu on it. Could someone please explain the following:

Where are the drivers for my computer (Acer TravelMate 5742Z)? And if they don't exist, is it still possible to install Ubuntu without these drivers and still be able to connect to the internet, use my mousepad, webcam, etc.

Thank you very much

Comment: I have Acer TravelMate 3260 and Ubuntu 11.10 works good! I think it will work good with your notebook too.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Acer 5552 and all the drivers for Ubuntu are built in so unlike Windows you will not need to spend a lot of time locating and installing drivers.

Your Notebook should work just fine but you can always run ubuntu from a live cd to check that all your drivers and devices are compatible, this way you will not risk a device causing you issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing by booting form the Ubuntu LiveCD, and then choosing "Try Ubuntu"? This will allow you to see what works, and what doesn't.

Often most drivers will be activated automatically, and if there is something proprietary, there will be an option to install Restricted Drivers. To try Ubuntu in "LiveCD" mode, make sure you download the 'Desktop' CD rather than the 'Alternate'.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my Acer TM5742Z, everything seems to be fine, sound, webcam, wi-fi, etc.... I have problems with the "function keys", i.e.: I am not able to change the bright of my display using the Fn + Left arrow or Fn + Right arrow